# Is there a way to set global parameters in TestNG?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, testng, ui-automation

I'm currently automating web app using Selenium WebDriver framework together with TestNG. I want to provide parameters for each test classes within testing.xml file, but on the web resources, I've seen only approach where certain parameters are predefined to use for single classes like:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Parameterization Test Suite">
<test name="Testing Parameterization">
<parameter name="browser" value="Firefox"/>
<parameter name="username" value="testuser"/>
<parameter name="password" value="testpassword"/>
    <classes>
        <class name="com.parameterization.TestParameters" />
    </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

where the class name, clearly states only one TestParameters class.

Is there any way to set some parameters right there as global ones? So we can use them in any test class within the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure if I understand your question, but you can define parameters on suite level (for each test, in the example `suite-param`), or on test level:

As taken from https://howtodoinjava.com/testng/testng-test-parameters-through-testng-xml-and-parameters-annotation/

```
<suite name="Parameter test Suite" verbose="1">
    <!-- This parameter will be passed to every test in this suite -->
    <parameter name="suite-param" value="suite level parameter" />
    <test name="Parameter Test one">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.howtodoinjava.test.ParameterTest">
                <methods>
                    <include name="prameterTestOne" />
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Parameter Test two">
        <!-- This parameter will be passed this test only -->
        <parameter name="test-two-param" value="Test two parameter" />
        <classes>
            <class name="com.howtodoinjava.test.ParameterTest">
                <methods>
                    <include name="prameterTestTwo" />
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Parameter Test three">
        <!-- Overriding suite level parameter -->
        <parameter name="suite-param" value="overiding suite parameter" />
        <!-- Test specific parameter -->
        <parameter name="test-three-param" value="test three parameter" />
        <classes>
            <class name="com.howtodoinjava.test.ParameterTest">
                <methods>
                    <include name="prameterTestThree" />
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: You got me right, and it looks like a solution, thanks !